# Data type for ssn number

Tags: sql-server

I need to give a datatype for the hashed value of a 4digit ssn number and for hashed value of a 9 digit ssn number.Do the hashed values of both 4 digit and 9 digit turn into a same length?

Comment: What length of varchar( ) should i give for both 4 digits and 9 digits

Comment: Generally for SSN numbers varchar(11) is recommended!

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing them down as hashes using the hashbytes function, I believe all the functions will output a binary string of identical length. If you're just casting the numbers to something like varbinary, the lengths will be different. I'd personally be inclined to store the hash as binary, and just allow for as many characters as the hashing algorithm requires.

```
select 
    hashbytes('sha1', '123-45-6789'),
    hashbytes('sha1', '6789')
```

Comment: Just a comment on hashing. DO NOT DO SOMETHING LIKE `hashbytes('sha1', '123-45-6789')` EVER for sensitive information. It is easily reversible (we generate all possible SSN's and hash them, then by hash we look up the SSN). SSN must be salted before hashing. It would be good to have different salt for each SSN. Salt should be appended to SSN (not prepended).

Comment: Excellent point, @n0rd. It's certainly not cryptographically secure as is.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the `varchar` datatype for SSN

> Do the hashed values of both 4 digit and 9 digit turn into a same
>   length?

I dont think that it would be same as SSN will include area number, group number, and serial number so if it is stored as `varchar` then it would not be same when hashed.